# Quorum nodes run fine with docker-compose, but crash when deployed on kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, quorum

Following the steps outlined [here](https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/latest/Tutorials/Create-IBFT-Network/), I created a basic Quorum network with 4 nodes and IBFT consensus. I then created a docker image for each of the nodes, copying the contents of each node's directory on to the image. The image was created from the official `quorumengineering/quorum` image, and when started as a container it executes the geth command. An example Dockerfile follows (different nodes have different rpcports/ports):

```
FROM quorumengineering/quorum
WORKDIR /opt/node
COPY . /opt/node
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore nohup geth --datadir data --nodiscover --istanbul.blockperiod 5 --syncmode full --mine --minerthreads 1 --verbosity 5 --networkid 10 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 22001 --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,istanbul  --rpcvhosts="*" --emitcheckpoints --port 30304
```

I then made a docker-compose file to run the images.

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  qnode0-data:
  qnode1-data:
  qnode2-data:
  qnode3-data:
services:
  qnode0:
    container_name: qnode0
    image: <myDockerHub>/qnode0
    ports:
      - 22000:22000
      - 30303:30303
    volumes:
      - qnode0-data:/opt/node
  qnode1:
    container_name: qnode1
    image: <myDockerHub>/qnode1
    ports:
      - 22001:22001
      - 30304:30304
    volumes:
      - qnode1-data:/opt/node
  qnode2:
    container_name: qnode2
    image: <myDockerHub>/qnode2
    ports:
      - 22002:22002
      - 30305:30305
    volumes:
      - qnode2-data:/opt/node
  qnode3:
    container_name: qnode3
    image: <myDockerHub>/qnode3
    ports:
      - 22003:22003
      - 30306:30306
    volumes:
      - qnode3-data:/opt/node
```

When running these images locally with docker-compose, the nodes start and I can even see the created blocks via a blockchain explorer. However, when I try to run this in a kubernetes cluster, either locally with minikube, or on AWS, the nodes do not start but rather crash.
To deploy on kubernetes I made the following three yaml files for each node (12 files in total):

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: qnode0
  name: qnode0
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: qnode0
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: qnode0
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <myDockerHub>/qnode0
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: qnode0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 22000
        - containerPort: 30303
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/node
          name: qnode0-data
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes:
      - name: qnode0-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: qnode0-data
status: {}
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: qnode0-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: qnode0
  ports:
    - name: rpcport
      protocol: TCP
      port: 22000
      targetPort: 22000
    - name: netlistenport
      protocol: TCP
      port: 30303
      targetPort: 30303
```

persistentvolumeclaim.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app: qnode0-data
  name: qnode0-data
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
```

When trying to run on a kubernetes cluster, each node runs into this error:

```
ERROR[] Cannot start mining without etherbase    err="etherbase must be explicitly specified"
Fatal: Failed to start mining: etherbase missing: etherbase must be explicitly specified
```

which does not occur when running locally with docker-compose. After examining the logs, I saw there is a difference between how the nodes startup locally with docker-compose and on kubernetes, which is the following lines:

locally I see the following lines in each node's output:

```
INFO [] Initialising Ethereum protocol           name=istanbul versions="[99 64]" network=10 dbversion=7
...
DEBUG[] InProc registered                        namespace=istanbul
```

on kubernetes (either in minikube or AWS) I see these lines differently:

```
INFO [] Initialising Ethereum protocol           name=eth versions="[64 63]" network=10 dbversion=7
...
DEBUG[] IPC registered                           namespace=eth
DEBUG[] IPC registered                           namespace=ethash
```

Why is this happening? What is the significance of `name=istanbul/eth`? My common sense logic says that the error happens because of the use of `name=eth`, instead of `name=istanbul`. But I don't know the significance of this, and more importantly, I don't know what it is I did to inadvertently affect the kubernetes deployment.

Any ideas how to fix this?

**EDIT**

I tried to address what [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) mentioned in his comment, i.e. that the node directory gets overwritten, so I created a new directory in the image with

`RUN mkdir /opt/nodedata/`

and used that to mount volumes in kubernetes. I also used StatefulSets instead of Deployments in kubernetes. The relevant yaml follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: qnode0
spec:
  serviceName: qnode0
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: qnode0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: qnode0
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <myDockerHub>/qnode0
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: qnode0
        ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          containerPort: 22000
        - protocol: TCP
          containerPort: 30303
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/nodedata
          name: qnode0-data
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes:
      - name: qnode0-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: qnode0-data
```

Changing the volume mount immediately produced the correct behaviour of

```
INFO [] Initialising Ethereum protocol           name=istanbul
```

However, I had networking issues, which I solved by using the environment variables that kubernetes sets for each service, which include the IP each service is running at, e.g.:

```
QNODE0_PORT_30303_TCP_ADDR=172.20.115.164
```

I also changed my kubernetes services a little, as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: qnode0
  name: qnode0
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "22000"
    port: 22000
    targetPort: 22000
  - name: "30303"
    port: 30303
    targetPort: 30303
  selector:
    app: qnode0
```

Using the environment variables to properly initialise the quorum files solved the networking problem.

**However**, when I delete my stateful sets and my services with:

`kubectl delete -f <my_statefulset_and_service_yamls>`

and then apply them again:

`kubectl apply -f <my_statefulset_and_service_yamls>`

quorum starts from scratch, i.e. it does not continue block creation from where it stopped but starts from 1 again, as follows:

`Inserted new block                       number=1 hash=1c99d0…fe59bb`

So the state of the blockchain is not saved, as was my initial fear. What should I do to address this?

Comment: Your PersistentVolumeClaim mount is overwriting everything the Dockerfile `COPY`s into  the image.  You'll likely get the same error if you change your Compose setup to bind-mount a host directory instead of a named volume.  Use a different directory for your application data; don't store it in the same place as the application code.

Comment: (Using a different image for each node seems a little unusual to me; in Kubernetes I'd expect to see a single StatefulSet with `replicas: 4` and a single Service.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the comments. When you say that the data get overwritten I guess you mean at the docker container layer, not the image layer. However, I do not understand how the ```PersistentVolumeClaim``` does this. Could you perhaps elaborate on this? In the node directory there is no application code, just the data (account data, private keys etc) of the private blockchain's node. The Quorum nodes are not 4 of the same. Each one is a different entity in a network, hence the different ports they use. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's just like any other Unix mount: when you mount something over a directory, you only see the mounted content; whatever was in the filesystem originally (in this case, the image content) is completely hidden.  You might need to restructure your image to separate persistent data from configuration.

Comment: @DavidMaze So, suppose you have any application where it needs to keep some data in a directory, which, however, is initially NOT empty. Eg, it has some initial data for the application to start with. If I understand you correctly, no such application would be able to run on kubernetes. We would have to restructure it. But what if the application is a third party one, where we don't have a say in where or how the app stores its data? I find it strange that kubernetes doesn't cater for the deployment of such applications. Although it is very possible that I have misunderstood you. Again thanks!

Comment: @zerzevul Does the above solve your issue?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor What's "the above"? I have solved the issue and will post an answer when I find the time.